# How to install webp-ffi using ruby gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When I try to run `gem install webp-ffi -v '0.2.5'` I'm getting an error saying:

`LoadError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.so`

I've intalled these:

```
libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libwebp-dev
```

and gems:

```
$ gem list --local | grep ffi    
ffi (1.15.4, 1.9.24)
ffi-compiler (1.0.1)
```

the error says:

> .../gems/**ffi-1.15.4**/lib/ffi_c.so

and I've already installed the version `1.15.4`

The full error log:

```
$ gem install webp-ffi -v '0.2.5'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing webp-ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/webp-ffi-0.2.5/ext/webp_ffi
/home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -rrubygems /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/webp-ffi-0.2.5 RUBYLIBDIR=/home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/webp-ffi-0.2.5
rake aborted!
LoadError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.so


Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.5/ffi_c


Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi-compiler/compile_task

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/webp-ffi-0.2.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/webp-ffi-0.2.5/gem_make.out
```

Ubuntu version: 20.04.3 (focal)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 : Installing the Ubuntu 21.10 `libffi8` ......... `sudo gdebi libffi8_3.4.2-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb` https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/libffi8/download .......... No issues, no dependencies.